# How to find min and max date across columns in SAS data set?

Tags: date, sas, max, minimum

I have a data set of following type

```
data have;
input subjid  var1$ var2$ var3$ var4$ var5$ var6$;
datalines;
121 23jan2022 24jan2022 20jan2022  24jan2022 26jan2022 25jan2022 
122 20jan2022 22jan2022 26jan2022  28jan2022 23jan2022 27jan2022 
;
run;
```

[image]

How can find the minimum date in all row across `var1` to `var3` and maximum date across `var4` to `var6` and then find the difference between maximum and minimum date.

The expected outcome is
[image]

In first row, `6` is the difference of `26jan2022 (this is max of var4-var6)` and `20jan2022 (this is min date of var1-var3)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*. It covers program input as well.

Comment: Why are you defining the variables as character strings if you want to treat them as dates?

Comment: If those are SAS dates use the RANGE function. `diff = range(of var1-var6);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variables are actual date values.

```
data have;
  input subjid $  (var1-var6) (:date.);
  format var1-var6 date9.;
datalines;
121 23jan2022 24jan2022 20jan2022  24jan2022 26jan2022 25jan2022 
122 20jan2022 22jan2022 26jan2022  28jan2022 23jan2022 27jan2022 
;
```

Then just use the MIN() and MAX() functions to find the min and max dates.  Once you have those simple subtraction will find the difference (range of dates).

```
data want;
  set have;
  mindate = min(of var1-var3);
  maxdate = max(of var4-var6);
  diff = maxdate-mindate;
  format mindate maxdate date9.;
run;
```

Results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data have;
    length subjid $3. var1 $9. var2 $9. var3 $9. var4 $9. var5 $9. var6 $9.;
    input subjid $ var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $ var5 $ var6 $;
datalines;
121 23jan2022 24jan2022 20jan2022 24jan2022 26jan2022 25jan2022 
122 20jan2022 22jan2022 26jan2022 28jan2022 23jan2022 27jan2022 
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    array var {*} var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6;
    array _var {*} _var1 _var2 _var3 _var4 _var5 _var6;

    do i=1 to dim(var);
        _var{i}=input(var{i}, date9.);
        if _var{i}=min(_var1, _var2, _var3) then var_min=var{i};
        if _var{i}=max(_var4, _var5, _var6) then var_max=var{i};
    end;
    var_diff=max(_var4, _var5, _var6)-min(_var1, _var2, _var3);

    format _var1 _var2 _var3 _var4 _var5 _var6 YYMMDD10.;
    drop i;
run;
```